# Flutter Map to a list of custom objects

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting back information from a websocket that might contain one or more items on each response.

I want to convert these responses to a list of custom objects.

The issue I have is where I want to use the first index (key) and second index (value) of the returned data and use them to pass into the custom object initialization to instantiate them and add them to the list.

I also want to add to the list, but if the 'name' field in an object already exists then just update that objects amount value instead of adding another copy. I will just do this with a loop, unless there is a shorter way.

Below you can see some of the attempts I have tried.

EDIT:

```
  var listAmounts = valueMap.values.toList();
  var listNames = valueMap.keys.toList();
  print(listAmounts[0]);
  print(listNames[0]);

for (int i = 0; i < listAmounts.length; i++) {
    Person newPerson =
        new Person(name: listNames[i], amount: double.parse(listAmounts[i]));
    coins.add(newPerson);
    print('=========');
    print(newPerson.name);
    print(newPerson.amount.toString());
    print('=========');
  }
```

I am not sure this is a good way as would there be a possibility that the keys/values will not be in order? From testing they are but I am not 100% sure?

Here are two examples of the message received from the websocket:

**example 1**

```
{jacob: 123.456789, steven: 47.3476543}
```

**example 2**

```
{henry: 54.3768574}
```

I have a custom class:

```
class Person {
  double amount;
  String name;

  Person({
    this.name = '',
    this.amount = 0.0,
  });
}
```

Here is the main code:

```
 IOWebSocketChannel channel;
 List<Person> people = [];

 void openChannel() async {
 channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
        "wss://ws.example.com/example?example=exp1,exp2,exp3");

    channel.stream.listen((message) {
      //print(message);
      Map valueMap = json.decode(message);
      print(valueMap);
      //people = List<Person>.from(valueMap.map((i) => Person.fromJson(i)));
      //message.forEach((name, amount) => people.add(Person(name: name, amount: amount)));
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you update the Person class above and include the named constructor `fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)`?

Comment: I tried adding:   fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    this.name = json[0];
    this.amount = amount.parse(json[1]);
  }  but got: instance member fromJson can't be accessed using static access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var listAmounts = valueMap.values.toList();
  var listNames = valueMap.keys.toList();
  print(listAmounts[0]);
  print(listNames[0]);

for (int i = 0; i < listAmounts.length; i++) {
    Person newPerson =
        new Person(name: listNames[i], amount: double.parse(listAmounts[i]));
    coins.add(newPerson);
    print('=========');
    print(newPerson.name);
    print(newPerson.amount.toString());
    print('=========');
  }
```

Comment: Can I see the printed values of `listAmounts` & `listNames`?